# apt problem,, cant install nor update nor upgrade

Tags: apt, kali-linux

Can't use `apt` I am using `kali linux 64 bit`, here is what the machine shows:

```
apt-get update
Ign:1 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling InRelease
Ign:2 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling Release
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib all Packages
Hit:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en_IN
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main all Packages
Hit:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main Translation-en
Ign:13 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main Translation-en_IN
Ign:14 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free all Packages
Hit:18 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:18 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:19 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en_IN
Ign:20 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en
Ign:21 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib all Packages
Hit:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en_IN
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main all Packages
Hit:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main Translation-en
Ign:13 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main Translation-en_IN
Ign:14 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free all Packages
Hit:18 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:18 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:19 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en_IN
Ign:20 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en
Ign:21 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib all Packages
Hit:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en_IN
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main all Packages
Hit:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
Ign:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main Translation-en
Ign:13 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main Translation-en_IN
Ign:14 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free all Packages
Hit:18 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:18 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:19 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en_IN
Ign:20 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en
Ign:21 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib all Packages
Hit:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en_IN
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main all Packages
Hit:11 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main Translation-en
Ign:13 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main Translation-en_IN
Ign:14 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:15 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free all Packages
Hit:18 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:19 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en_IN
Ign:20 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en
Ign:21 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib all Packages
Hit:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en_IN
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main all Packages
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main Translation-en
Ign:13 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main Translation-en_IN
Ign:14 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:15 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free all Packages
Ign:19 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en_IN
Ign:20 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en
Ign:21 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:3 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib all Packages
Ign:5 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en
Ign:6 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib Translation-en_IN
Ign:7 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:8 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:9 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main all Packages
Ign:12 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main Translation-en
Ign:13 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main Translation-en_IN
Ign:14 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Hit:4 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign:15 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:16 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free all Packages
Ign:19 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en_IN
Ign:20 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free Translation-en
Ign:21 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'cdrom://[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170416-02:08] kali-rolling Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to your question please.

Comment: i edited that,,

Comment: still cant use apt-get install to install the things that i want

Comment: "***need help quick***", really? I suggest you start with removing anything that is NOT relevant in your question ... AND remove the "quick" from your last phrase ... As a reminder: any comment / answer comes from users who contribute there (free?) time ...

Comment: Please read this https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question appropriately. Provide as many pertinent details as you can. Leave the noise out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[What should my sources.list look like?](https://docs.kali.org/faq/kali-sources-list-faq)

> Kali rolling users should have these entries in their `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Remove the cdrom repository from your sources.list which cause the problem.

Open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list
apt update && apt upgrade
```