# Cannot use apt-get update: Repository ... does not have a release file

Tags: kali-linux

I installed kali on my acer predator helios 300 alongside Windows 10. I couldn't get past the login screen because it gets stuck after entering the credentials. So I googled it and found the issue was with some graphic drivers and so I ctrl+alt+f2 ed at the login screen and got a terminal. My sources.list file  was like this

```
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2018.4 _Kali-rolling -  Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20181016-16:07] kali-last-snapshot contrib main non-free
#This system was installed using small removable media
#(e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
#entries were disabled at the end of the installation process
#For information about how to configure apt package sources
#see the sources.list(5) manual
```

So I added this line to the sources.list file to update apt and install Nvidia drivers.

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

And when I run apt-get update it says

```
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling main InRelease
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling main Release
 404 Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling main Release' does not have a release file.
N: Updating from suck a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: per https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories there's no "/dists" in the path...

Comment: Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/388471/117549

Comment: Funny; I wonder if the error has a typo or if it was mis-copied: "Updating from suck a repository ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to read [05. Using Kali Linux / Kali sources.list Repositories](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories), which gives the correct entry for your `sources.list` file:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```