# Can't get updates to Kali with updated source.list: "does not have a Release file"

Tags: apt, kali-linux, software-updates

My question is similar to [other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500913/316437) ask in the past but it's **different**, my `source.file` is correct based on Kali and I still have issue with update.

My `source.list` file:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

When I run `apt-get update` I get:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling Release
  404   Not Found [IP: 192.99.200.113 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling Relase' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What else can be the problem?

My Kali Linux version:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# uname -a
Linux kali 4.19.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.28-2kali1 (2019-03-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I also verify the `source.list` content by this page:
https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it after I clean the apt manager by running:

```
apt-get clean && apt-get purge && apt autoremove
```

I think the `apt autoremove` did the job.
After that I run:  `apt-get update` and it seems to be fixed.

Comment: When I run that I get E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Comment: Yes, I was root